# Ошибка:SQLiteException: no such table while compiling

Tags: java, android

Запускаю на реальном устройстве, root права есть. Предполагаю,что ошибка в коде, нежели аппаратная часть.
Базу данных скопировал в папку:
**app\src\main\res\assets\database**

Сама ошибка:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: coordinate.db (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM coordinate.db ORDER BY  column DESC LIMIT 1
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
                                                                         at com.pokemongo.pokemon.CameraViewActivity.randomCoordinate(CameraViewActivity.java:274)
                                                                         at com.pokemongo.pokemon.CameraViewActivity.onCreate(CameraViewActivity.java:89)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5236)
```

Метод,в котором рандомно из таблицы берутся координаты:

```
private void randomCoordinate() {


   ArrayList<Double> latitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> longitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    String queryLatitude = "SELECT * FROM coordinate.db ORDER BY  column DESC LIMIT 1";
    String queryLongitude = "SELECT * FROM coordinate.db ORDER BY  column DESC LIMIT 1";

    Cursor cLatitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
    Cursor cLongitude  =  sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLongitude, null);
    if(cLatitude != null)
    {
        while(cLatitude.moveToNext()){
            latitudesAr.add(cLatitude.getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LATITUDE)));
        }
    }
    if(cLongitude != null)
    {
        while(cLongitude.moveToNext()){
            longitudesAr.add(cLatitude.getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LONGITUDE)));
        }
    }
    //получаем рандомно выбранные индексы
    Random r = new Random();
    int indexLatitude = r.nextInt(latitudesAr.size());
    int indexLongitude = r.nextInt(longitudesAr.size());
    //присваиваем переменным
    mMyLatitude = latitudesAr.get(indexLatitude);
    mMyLongitude = longitudesAr.get(indexLongitude);

}
```

ругается на эту строку:

```
 Cursor cLatitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
```

Вызываю в методе  oncreate главного класса randomCoordinate();

Класс БД:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.pokemongo.pokemon.database/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "coordinate.db";
private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
static final String TABLE = "users";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
public SQLiteDatabase database;
private Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    this.myContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void create_db() {
    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            //получаем локальную бд как поток
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // Путь к новой бд
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            // Открываем пустую бд
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // побайтово копируем данные
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

}

**UPDATE:
метод:**

```
private void randomCoordinate() {

    ArrayList<Double> latitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> longitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    String queryLatitude = "SELECT * FROM coordinates ORDER BY  _id DESC LIMIT 1";
    String queryLongitude = "SELECT * FROM coordinates ORDER BY  _id DESC LIMIT 1";

    Cursor cLatitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
    Cursor cLongitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLongitude, null);
    if (cLatitude != null) {
        while (cLatitude.moveToNext()) {
            latitudesAr.add(cLatitude
                    .getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LATITUDE)));
        }
    }
    if (cLongitude != null) {
        while (cLongitude.moveToNext()) {
            longitudesAr.add(cLatitude
                    .getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LONGITUDE)));
        }
    }
    //получаем рандомно выбранные индексы
    Random r = new Random();
    int indexLatitude = r.nextInt(latitudesAr.size());
    int indexLongitude = r.nextInt(longitudesAr.size());
    //присваиваем переменным
    mMyLatitude = latitudesAr.get(indexLatitude);
    mMyLongitude = longitudesAr.get(indexLongitude);

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE 2**

```
 private void randomCoordinate() {

    ArrayList<Double> latitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> longitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    String queryLatitude =
            "SELECT * FROM \" + coordinates + \" ORDER BY \" + id +\" DESC LIMIT 1";
    String queryLongitude =
            "SELECT * FROM \" + coordinates + \" ORDER BY  \" + id +\" DESC LIMIT 1";
    try {
        Cursor cLatitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLatitude, null);
        Cursor cLongitude = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(queryLongitude, null);

        if (cLatitude != null) {
            while (cLatitude.moveToNext()) {
                latitudesAr.add(cLatitude
                        .getDouble(cLatitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LATITUDE)));
            }
        }
        if (cLongitude != null) {
            while (cLongitude.moveToNext()) {
                longitudesAr.add(cLongitude
                        .getDouble(cLongitude.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LONGITUDE)));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ошибка получения колонок бд", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    //получаем рандомно выбранные индексы
    Random r = new Random();
    int indexLatitude = r.nextInt(latitudesAr.size());
    int indexLongitude = r.nextInt(longitudesAr.size());
    //присваиваем переменным
    mMyLatitude = latitudesAr.get(indexLatitude);
    mMyLongitude = longitudesAr.get(indexLongitude);

}
```

Ошибка:
вываливается тут:

```
 int indexLatitude = r.nextInt(latitudesAr.size());
```

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В SQL-запросе после SELECT * FROM должна быть указана какая то таблица в базе, а не имя самой базы. В ошибке сказано, что в базе нет таблицы с именем coordinate.db, что естественно.

Имя таблицы у вас, видимо, *users*, судя по константам, хотя SQL команды на создание БД нет, так как вы ее копируете и имена таблиц в своей базе знать можете только вы.

PS. Сортировка по какому-то полю (столбцу)  *column* выглядит тоже весьма подозрительно, вы уверены, что в вашей таблице есть такой столбец.

Comment: учел все ваши замечания,но ничего не помогло!
обновил шапку

Comment: @upward какая ошибка теперь?

Comment: @ pavlofff
эта же,я скриншот же прикрепил

Comment: @ pavlofff
нашел ошибку,оглвил код,теперь другая)но уже не из это песни

Comment: @upward Поскольку это совсем другая проблема, создайте новый вопрос. Этот вопрос приведите в первоначальный вид, чтобы ответ соответствовал вопросу, таковы правила данного ресрса. Если мой ответ решил первоначальную проблему, отметьте его верным